# Оптимальный способ организации хранения сообщений в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Допустим, мы создаём сайт с возможностью обмена сообщениями между зарегистрированными пользователями. Как лучше организовать хранение таких сообщений?

Привожу все варинты, о которых я думал (скорее всего, все они не подходят для практического применения, но может у Вас будет что добавить к тому, что я написал).

- Хранение сообщений в общей таблице БД, в которой есть булевские поля "Отображать у отправителя" и "Отображать у получателя" для реализации функции удаления писем (когда оба поля имеют false, сообщение удаляется из таблицы). Недостаток такого подхода - высокий уровень путаницы и возрастающее по мере увеличения пользователей и их сообщений время поиска по таблице. Достоинство - нет дублирования сообщений к в следующих вариантах.
- При добавлении нового пользователя создать под каждого пользователя таблицу с сообщениями. Достоинство - быстрее поиск, чем в первом варианте, а также логическое разделение. Недостатки - дублирование сообщений в двух БД, сложности с организацией имён таблиц в БД, а так же стремительный рост занимаемой памяти с каждым новым добавлением таблиц.
- Создать новую БД под каждого пользователя, где будут таблицы "Входящие", "Исходящие" и многие другие, не связанные конкретно с данной задачей. Достоинство - максимальный уровень организации данных по типу "один пользователь - одна БД" со всеми его данными. Недостаток - стремительный рост занимаемой памяти с каждой новой БД.
- Хранить сообщение в файлах. Тут без комментариев.

Если в целом о БД и их обработке говорить трудно, то в данном вопросе будем по умолчанию использовать MySQL и PHP для обработки.

Comment: `Недостаток такого подхода - высокий уровень путаницы и возрастающее по мере увеличения пользователей и их сообщений время поиска по таблице.` - вы там вручную будете сообщения искать? Алгоритму совершенно без разницы сколько там пользователей и сколько сообщений. Для ускорения поиска и выборки нужно создать индексы на полях условий.

Comment: Означает ли Ваш комментарий, что первый вариант подходит?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа. Его можно закрыть с формулировкой `необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ`. Но я считаю, что для всех личных сообщений достаточно 1 таблицы, в которой будут поля: сообщение, дата сообщения, отправитель, получатель, флаг отправителя, флаг получателя.

Comment: Насчёт "не имеет однозначного ответа" не соглашусь, потому что если привести по каждому пункту набор плюсов и минусов с аргументацией, то это будет достаточно объективно. Другое дело, найдётся ли тот, кто великодушно убъёт на это своё драгоценное время...

Comment: @Visman, оформили бы комментарий как ответ. Он верный и однозначный. Все остальные, что предложил автор, это бред сумасшедшего.

Comment: В большинстве случаев достаточно первого варианта, вопрос производительности решается созданием индексов на ключевые поисковые поля. Запросы к разным таблицам или тем более к разным БД внесет только большую путаницу, усложнит и будет тормозить систему.